# JSpinner not reacting on MouseWheelEvent on Windows

Tags: java, swing, mousewheel, mouselistener, jspinner

This is getting me quite confused:
I have a small application that uses a `JSpinner` for numeric values. I added a `MouseAdapter` to it, setting the value depending on the resulting event's `getScrollAmount()` and `getWheelRotation()`.

Everything is working quite fine as long as the application is run on linux (Debian Wheezy, Oracle JDK 1.6.0_32). That is, scrolling the mouse wheel while the JSpinner has focus works just fine (using GTK LookAndFeel).

Testing the software on Microsoft Windows exposed a different behavior:
The `JSpinner` will not react on mouse wheel movement. `LookAndFeel`s don't seem to be a problem here, as i already tried `MetalLookAndFeel` on both Linux and Windows.

Any suggestions on how to get this JSpinner reacting on `MouseWheelEvent`s on both OSes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm im not sure what could be wrong, but here is code designed on windows 7 and it works fine so maybe try it out on yours and see where the code is different:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class JSpinnerMouse extends JFrame {

    private JSpinner jspinner;

    public JSpinnerMouse() {
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSpinnerMouse jSpinnerMouse = new JSpinnerMouse();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("JSpinner using mouse wheel");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addComponentsToContentPane(getContentPane());
        addListeners();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponentsToContentPane(Container contentPane) {
        jspinner = new JSpinner();
        contentPane.add(jspinner);
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        this.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent mwe) {
                if (MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL == mwe.getScrollType()) {
                    int value = (int) jspinner.getValue();
                    if (mwe.getWheelRotation() == -1) {//up
                        jspinner.setValue(value + 1);
                    } else {//down
                        jspinner.setValue(value - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also to mention, I could not find the getDirection() method in the MouseWheelEvent like you said you are using so i used the getUnitsToScroll() which will return either a positive or negative value depending on the direction. Maybe this is whats causing the trouble. Where did you find a getDirection() method in the MouseWheelEvent Class?

Comment: sorry for calling it `getDirection()`, actually I did use `getWheelRotation()` to get the direction. I will try out your suggestion ASAP, this appears to be just the thing!

Comment: oh i see, well i edited the above code to fit in with what you have done and it works on my windows perfectly

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! This did the trick and it works perfectly on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Debian GNU/Linux. I still wonder why `getWheelRotation()` failed me on Windows.

Comment: Okay, it appears it wasn't `getWheelRotation()`'s fault after all: Your updated code is working fine for my Windowses as well. Conclusion: Problem lies elsewhere, nevertheless, you made the point. Thank you.